# Помогите разобраться с решением задачи

Tags: javascript

Условие задачи: В localStorage по ключу "counters" находится JSON c объектом, полями которого являются имена счётчиков, а значениями - числовое значение счётчика.

Напишите функцию incrementCounter, которой на вход первым параметром передаётся counterName - имя счётчика.

Задача функции - увеличить значение счётчика counterName на 1 и обновить данные в localStorage.

В localStorage может находится не валидный JSON, чтение которого может привести к ошибке, в этом случае функция должна записывать новые данные, где у указанного счетчика будет значение 1.

В конце функция должна возвращать значение счетчика после инкремента.

Пример использования:

```js
// в localStorage 1 счетчик: bannerClick = 5
incrementCounter('bannerClick'); // 6
incrementCounter('bannerClose'); // 1
// в localStorage 2 счетчика: bannerClick = 6, bannerClose = 1
```

Вот само решение:

```js
function incrementCounter(counterName){
     let counters;

    try {
        counters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("counters"));
    } catch (er) {
        counters = {};
    }
    if(typeof counters[counterName] !== 'number'){
        counters[counterName] = 0;
    }
    counters[counterName]++;
    localStorage.setItem("counters", JSON.stringify(counters));

    return counters[counterName];
}
```

1. Первое меня интересует блоки try/catch.
   В try мы в новоиспеченную переменную заносим значения ключа counters из localStorage, сразу же запарсивая.
   А что происходит в блоке catch? Почему там написано `counters = {}`?
2. Почему в условии пишут `counters[counterName]`?
   Это обращение к значению счетчика, находящегося в localStorage? И почему, если тип `counters[counterName]` НЕ number, то ему присваивается значение 0? Это для случая, если будут записываться новые данные?
3. В предпоследней строчке в localStorage заносится `counters`, а почему не `counters[counterName]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Почему там написано counters = {}?**
   Изначально `counters` не присваивается никакого значение, так что если происходит ошибка и получить данные из **localStorage** не получится, дальнейший код выдаст ошибку. Чтобы этого избежать `counters` присваивается пустой объект.
2. **Почему в условии пишут counters[counterName]**
   Обычная скобочная нотация - обращение к полю объекта.
3. **Почему, если тип counters[counterName] НЕ number, то ему присваивается значение 0?**
   По названию очевидно, что `counter` - счётчик, он должен быть числом, а если он им не является, то ему присваивается значение 0.
4. **В предпоследней строчке в localStorage заносится counters, а почему не counters[counterName]?**
   А почему должно? `counters[counterName]` - одно значение из объекта, `counters` - все значения. Вам же надо сохранить все значения, а не только то которое вы изменили.

Comment: Что за сокращение "д.б числом" в 3 пункте?

Comment: д.б. = должен быть